# Syncing small changes to a large file to Cloud Storage

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I have a compute engine VM that makes small changes to a large file very often.

I want to sync those writes to GCS as often as possible.

Is my only option to constantly upload the complete large file on every small change? This would mean I am sending perhaps 99% unchanged bytes between my VM and GCS on every upload.

- Would this cost a lot of my VMs CPU, or would this operation be relatively cheap as its just sending bytes over the network?
- Would I be charged for all this redundant traffic?

Comment: could you store the file in GCS? What's the content of the file? Could you just send the diffs to GCS? What does "relative often" mean? How often per second/minute/hour/day?

Comment: I want the file in GCS to be a mirror copy of the large file that exists on the VMs disk. So the VM is the master, the GCS file is the slave. Its a SQLite DB.

Answer (score 1):

There is no easy answer to your question. The best answer depends on a careful review of many factors that go beyond your actual question.

> Is my only option to constantly upload the complete large file on
>   every small change?

If your goal is to mirror those changes to Google Cloud Storage, then yes, you have to constantly upload the entire file. Google Cloud Storage Objects are immutable. This means that you cannot change an existing object. You must upload a new object to overwrite the existing object. You could create a strategy of multiple objects that combined represent the SQLite database and then just update those objects that have changed.

> Would this cost a lot of my VMs CPU, or would this operation be
>   relatively cheap as its just sending bytes over the network?

Your question is vague. What does "cost a lot" mean. You will pay for network egress traffic from Google Compute Engine to Cloud Storage. How much depends on the type of Cloud Storage, locations of the Compute Engine instance and Cloud Storage bucket and the type of addressing used (public/private IP networks). Some combinations are free. Review the following links to determine your pricing.

[Network Pricing](https://cloud.google.com/compute/network-pricing)

[Cloud Storage Network Pricing](https://cloud.google.com/storage/pricing#network-pricing)

> Would I be charged for all this redundant traffic?

Yes. Google Cloud does not analyze your egress data to determine data duplication.

Your strategy of constantly copying a file to Cloud Storage needs to be reviewed. There are three primary factors to consider. There is a fourth that I will mention later in my answer.

1. RPO - Recovery Point Objective
2. RTO - Recovery Time Objective
3. Implementation Cost

The smaller the values for #1 and #2, this higher the cost. You need to decide what cost is reasonable for a given RPO and RTO.

Personally, I would not use Cloud Storage as a near real time replication system. If cost was my primary factor I would add another disk to the Compute Engine instance. Then periodically freeze the SQLite database and create a copy with timestamp on the second disk. At a slower interval I would then copy the replicated copies (timestamped object names) to Cloud Storage. How frequently each operation should be made depends on the three bullets above.

In the real world there are several types of scenarios that you should consider:

1. Data Loss
2. Data Corruption

Your strategy will fail if the database is corrupted or necessary data is deleted from the database. You are just blindly overwriting the backup object with no backup history. Your strategy needs to include "Point in Time" restores so that you can recover from a mistake such as deleting a table or a set of rows due to a bug or accident. In my experience, Point In Time Restores are more important than RTO (frequent backups) and sometimes more important than RPO (how much data loss can you accept). Humans make more mistakes, and more often, than computers.

Comment: "cost a lot" in terms of CPU. I mean is it an expensive operation in terms of CPU to constantly be moving bytes from disk over the network; I do not want to block application code that needs the CPU. I think the core issue is GCS not supporting patch operations. Disk snapshots seem to be the only alternative.

Comment: @zino - you propose a question without details. The amount of CPU depends on the instance size. If you are using an F1-micro, then yes, this is CPU expensive and network intensive for that instance size. I provided you with a very detailed answer with suggestions for what to consider. You are worrying about the wrong item.